# Laravel mass assignment ignore guarded

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a simple Laravel Eloquest Model with some fileable attributes and relations. This model is connected to DB, and worked good two months ago. After updating a table and adding a new column `status`, something become broken. Here is my model:

```
class Good extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product_goods';

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = ['sku', 'status'];

    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     * @noinspection PhpUnused
     */
    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     * @noinspection PhpUnused
     */
    public function color() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Color::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function sizes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Size::class, 'product_good_size');
    }

    /**
     * @return BelongsTo
     * @noinspection PhpUnused
     */
    public function sizeStandard() {
        return $this->belongsTo(SizeStandard::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return MorphMany
     * @noinspection PhpUnused
     */
    public function files() {
        return $this->morphMany(File::class, 'fileable')
            ->orderBy('show_priority');
    }

    /**
     * @return HasMany
     * @noinspection PhpUnused
     */
    public function prices() {
        return $this->hasMany(Price::class);
    }
}
```

Then i'm trying to `make()` this model like this:

```
$goodData = [
            'prices' => [
                'RUB' => 788,
                'UAH' => 499,
            ],
            'color_id' => Color::first()->id,
            'size_standard_id' => $sizeStandard->id,
            'sizes' => $sizeIds,
            'sku' => $faker->uuid,
            'files' => [
                ['file' => UploadedFile::fake(),],
                ['file' => UploadedFile::fake(),],
                ['file' => UploadedFile::fake(),],
                ['file' => UploadedFile::fake(),],
            ],
        ];

$good = Good::make($goodData);
```

Then i got illegal attributes, which I dont want to see. I need only fillable attributes, but i see whole data, which is wrong.

```
App\Models\Product\Good^ {#1207
  #table: "product_goods"
  +incrementing: false
  #fillable: array:2 [
    0 => "sku"
    1 => "status"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [
    "prices" => array:2 [
      "RUB" => 788
      "UAH" => 499
    ]
    "color_id" => "6922c4e9-462f-4ce8-8028-36116845f0ea"
    "size_standard_id" => "5f367199-c28a-4dc7-a979-d46f019eb2ac"
    "sizes" => array:6 [
      0 => array:1 [
        "id" => "275c9efd-f5b6-437c-b0f1-a05c278404bd"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [
        "id" => "3090beb1-7fd3-4f79-9977-1d78abf83d09"
      ]
      2 => array:1 [
        "id" => "3121d205-101e-4cf1-8130-1bd94a2c255d"
      ]
      3 => array:1 [
        "id" => "b903d4c0-d33d-4191-8fb5-9b625b06ef7f"
      ]
      4 => array:1 [
        "id" => "deddbd28-4e72-46bc-b317-8ab8a68c2ed7"
      ]
      5 => array:1 [
        "id" => "f4139b5a-b703-4cd0-a29a-44f66aae18fc"
      ]
    ]
    "sku" => "62471d6b-04c6-3b88-a9af-2960f96b78a9"
    "files" => array:4 [
      0 => array:1 [
        "file" => Illuminate\Http\Testing\FileFactory^ {#1162}
      ]
      1 => array:1 [
        "file" => Illuminate\Http\Testing\FileFactory^ {#1187}
      ]
      2 => array:1 [
        "file" => Illuminate\Http\Testing\FileFactory^ {#1164}
      ]
      3 => array:1 [
        "file" => Illuminate\Http\Testing\FileFactory^ {#1157}
      ]
    ]
    "status" => "active"
  ]
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of this ```Good::make($goodData);``` method please.

Comment: `make()` is the base Model method.

Comment: Hmm, never used it before. Tried in tinker, and it behaves as you described. It is affected by fillable. You will likely need to debug manually in ```Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder```'s ```make()``` method, which ultimately leads to ```Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model```'s ```newInstance()``` method.

Comment: @kurt-friars, I tested more simple way with constructor and `fill()` method, and got the same result.

Comment: Very bizarre behavior! Hopefully someone can lend some insight, otherwise let us know what you find out from debugging it.

Comment: Are you running this code inside a seeder?

Comment: Are you just trying to hide other attributes except sku and status while retrieving modal ?

Comment: @kurt-friars I`m running this code inside seeder....

Comment: @Egretos please see answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `$faker->uuid` I am assuming you are trying to call `make()` while seeding.

Mass Assignment restrictions are turned off during seeding. If you would like your model to respect Mass Assignment restrictions, you can use:

```
Good::reguard();

Good::make($goodData);
```

Comment: That`s right! This code was running inside Seeder! Thanks! You save my day :)

Comment: Yah, its an obscure case! Glad to help :)